# print_r Return Value Incorrect

Tags: php, debugging

I am having a little trouble with the `print_r` function.  Undoubtedly something I am misunderstanding in its operation... Basically, I have an array of objects in a class like so:

```
public $fields = array();
```

Assigned like so:

```
$oField = new Field();
/* property assignments to $oField omitted for brevity */
$this->fields[$i] = $oField;
```

Now in the primary class, I am attempting to capture debug information:

```
$this->debuginfo = print_r($this->fields, true);
```

When outputting the value of `$this->debuginfo`, it simply says "Array" - basically not exploding the array. If I do a regular `print_r($this->fields);`, it gives the expected results.

This is my first time attempting to use `print_r` with it returning results versus outputting to the screen so I am sure I am just missing something, but in reading the php documentation, this is how it would *seem* to be implemented. What am I missing?

Thanks for any assistance!

**Update:**
`print_r($var, true)` does indeed return the "exploded" variable properly as I had it written.  Thanks to *dev-null* for their comment which gave me some food for thought that lead me to my problem.

Comment: How do you output `$this->debuginfo`?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Are the properties of the Field class protected, private, or static?

Comment: I am actually saving the value to a database.  The field in the database contains the "Array".

Comment: PHP version is 5.3.3.  All of the properties of the Field class are public.

Comment: I don't think it's related to `print_r`. Somewhere in your code `$this->debuginfo` must be replaced by an array and while saving to db it is casted to string, hence `Array`;

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is the field in the table you're saving the data to actually large enough to store the data? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try **var_export()** instead. var_export() gets structured information about the given variable.

example:

```
$this->debuginfo = var_export($this->fields, true);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php